# In a Lithium Ion battery (during discharge) positive Li Ions flow to the +3.8 volt cathode. Where do they get the energy to climb that 3.8 V hill?

Tags: batteries, electrochemistry

These positive $\text{Li}$ ions are flowing up hill to the cathode during discharge so where is the energy coming from that allows them to get over the hill?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Li+ ion move to cathode in Li-ion battery?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169050/why-does-li-ion-move-to-cathode-in-li-ion-battery)